# Introduction book for JBoss Application Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I joined a programming competition that requires participant to use JBoss Application Server platform. Do you guys have any recommendation on what books or articles I could use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Master the Boss](http://www.mastertheboss.com/) is the place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response Yishai.

Answer (score 1):

You can't go past the JBoss Community Documentation, specifically the [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Getting+Started+Guide)!

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).

Comment: Attempts to edit like this a decade after the original comment look like edit farming, rather than being helpful. Be more mindful of your context please, and ensure that the prevailing benefits to the users are maintained.

Answer (score 0):

About books, I was quite satisfied with the [JBoss AS 7 Book](http://www.packtpub.com/jboss-as-7-configuration-deployment-administration/book).
Hope it helps
Linda

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are looking a bit forward the [WildFly 8 book](http://www.itbuzzpress.com/ebooks/wildfly-8-book.html) has been just published. Best regards.